# Windows XP doesn't see a partition after removing Ubuntu. How to restore an access to it?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uninstall

I have removed Ubuntu from my dual-boot machine. I just manually deleted Ubuntu partition being under Windows. I used "Disk Manager" for that operation. Then I restarted the computer with Windows CD and restored MBR with Windows restore console and `fixmbr` command. Everything is OK, Windows boot works fine.

But now it seems that Windows doesn't see that partition (where Ubuntu was). I cannot create any new logical partition on that place. When I try to create a partition Windows throws an error. What happened and how can I restore the access to that partition from Windows?

I want to try Lubuntu (because Ubuntu was slow). I have 60 Gb partition dedicated for some Linux as the second OS. I want to allocate 10 Gb of it for a FAT32 shared partition. The rest (50 Gb) is for Lubuntu. It was exactly the same settings for Ubuntu. Now I want to do the same for Lubuntu, but Windows now cannot see that 60 Gb partition. How to restore the access?

When I try to create a partition Windows throws an error. It says:

> An unexpected error happened. Check a journal of system events. Close
> the window of the disk manager and start it again or restart a
> computer.

I tried both, I closed a window and restarted a computer. Didn't help. The error happens every time I try to create a partition on that place (60 Gb partition).

The error from the journal of system events:

> Source: LDM
>
> Category: no category
>
> Type: error
>
> ID: 2
>
> Text: Wrong parameter (80070057).

Comment: I think this is off-topic since it is a Windows question. Either way, you should edit your question to include the error message you receive. I still consider this off-topic, though.

Comment: @edwin I would say this could be borderline on-topic, questions about removing Ubuntu are on-topic and this could be considered as extension of that as his problem likely results directly from uninstalling Ubuntu....however, I agree that the OP needs to add more info to clarify his question.

Comment: Possibly, just possibly, the partition is `ext` formatted (or is not formatted) and that is why Windows can't see it. You can try installing Lubuntu to see if the installer can see the partition. Then you just need to leave  `10 GB` free for your FAT32 shared partition. (After installing Lubuntu, you would use GParted in Lubuntu to format this `10 GB` partition to FAT32.

Comment: @edwin, this is Ubuntu question, because it happened because of Ubuntu, after Ubuntu uninstall. The message is in Russian, I'll try translate it.

Comment: I agree with @TrailRider it is at the 'borderline' (because it is Windows that cannot see the partition). But never mind, these comments form a meta discussion (which is already off-topic! xD).

Comment: @edwin, you were right, for Windows Disk Manager that partition was not formatted at all. Lubuntu from Live CD could see that space, but Windows Disk Manager couldn't. I restarted Windows with Windows CD, created a new 10 GB partition from there in that space, then entered Windows as usual, and then formatted those 10 Gb as FAT32 with Disk Manager.

Answer (score 1):

So, somehow when you being under Windows manually delete a partition where Ubuntu is located, that partition cannot be recognized by Windows later, after you have deleted Ubuntu.

But it cannot be recognized only by Windows Disk Manager. Disk Manager just throws an error if you want to do something with that partition. But Ubuntu (or Lubuntu) sees that partition just fine.

So, this is what I did to get that partition back in Windows. I reboot Windows using Windows CD and from there I chose to create a new 10 Gb partition on that space. Then I entered Windows as usual and Disk Manager could see that new 10 Gb partition. I formatted it with FAT32.

So now I have 10 Gb FAT32 shared partition and 50 Gb for Lubuntu.